# Loading JS file with JS without a web page

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, loading

I have been researching for a simple solution to a problem that I have.

I have a JavaScript file that needs to use some functions that are contained in another JS file. I read many posts from stack overflow, and they all require a to be loaded from a web page. In my case they absolutely do not use a web page to be loaded and I do not want to use one.

The reason is because I am running JavaScript unit testing from command line using Rhino. Please I'm begging for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can load in the other javascript file using Ajax.  Have a look at [jQuery .getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).  I'm not sure if that'll work in the context of running from the command line, or if it just appends the .js file to the document.body.

Comment: There's more details about doing this in another Stack Overflow post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I already looked at that post @kah608, but the options used they all require a web browser, Thank you Duncan, by chance are you aware of any JavaScript Native commands? Will JQuery need a browser to be loaded though?

Answer (score 1):

Use Rhino's `load` function (about a third of the way down this page): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell